# Failed Review Audit - Question was marked as spam, but couldn't it have been salvaged?

Tags: discussion

[Here was the review.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7076633) I marked this as Should Be Improved because, although there was a link to a website (albeit of dubious morality), the user had a question that he was trying to have answered. With the link removed and replaced with more neutral context for the issue he was having, the question certainly could've been answered.

Should any question with a link such as this be marked as spam?

Comment: I don't see anything redeemable about that question.  it's a spam post that has some random technobabble mixed in to make it look like it's not spam at a glance; you fell for it.

Comment: spam or not, it should have definitely been closed asap.

Comment: And if you read the question... how do you think that could have possibly been answered? The chances of someone actually writing a script that prints that message targeted only at IE are pretty slim..

Comment: I'm sure your intentions were good.  The counter-argument when fighting spam is that by "heroic editing" you may further disguise the spamish nature of a poster.  Bear in mind it is not simply the post we want to block, but the poster.  Enough spam flags approved will get the account blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything redeemable about that question. it's a spam post that has some random technobabble mixed in to make it look like it's not spam at a glance; you fell for it.  That post should *absolutely* be marked as spam.

As a reviewer, finding and burning spam with fire is one of your *primary* purposes.  Letting spam get through the system is one of the most serious problems you can cause as a reviewer.

Comment: I was about to mark it as spam. But I still think there was some form of actual question in there. This was the first spam-worthy question I have seen after a couple hundred reviews. I'll take it to heart I guess.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj The user was pretending to ask a real question to get people to keep reading, and to ensure that the question's description from the question list wouldn't appear to be spam at a glance (which is also why the spam content is in a code block).  Nothing about the post in any way indicates that it's actually asking a serious question.  It's just trying to hide the spam in sheep's clothing.